# Change a file xml with maven plugin

Tags: plugins, maven, maven-3

I´m working with maven 3, migrating the old application using hivemind and ant. I need to change The file "Hivemodule.xml" with some properties with information about enviroment, I define with profile but it doesn´t work.
I try using maven-resources-plugin but without success, perhaps it just do with properties files.

Detail: The Hivemodule.xml is inside the file jar and I want to unpack this file to turn the content of internal hivemodule configurations and after, to pack again... I´m in the unpack fase.

Here is my file in Hivemodule.xml and the parameters that I want to turn:

```
PROVIDER_URL="ormi://localhost:23791/"
APPLICATION_NAME="services_1_11"
SECURITY_PRINCIPAL="oc4jadmin"
SECURITY_CREDENTIAL="welcome"
```

For use of profiles, I edited this file:

```
PROVIDER_URL="${PROVIDER_URL}"
APPLICATION_NAME="${APPLICATION_NAME}"
SECURITY_PRINCIPAL="${SECURITY_PRINCIPAL}"
SECURITY_CREDENTIAL="${SECURITY_CREDENTIAL}"
```

In my pom.xml, the references to profile:

```
<profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                <PROVIDER_URL>ormi://localhost:23791/</PROVIDER_URL>
                <APPLICATION_NAME>services_1_11</APPLICATION_NAME>
                <SECURITY_PRINCIPAL>oc4jadmin</SECURITY_PRINCIPAL>
                <SECURITY_CREDENTIAL>welcome</SECURITY_CREDENTIAL>
            </properties>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
```

And my resource configurations:

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${serviceSegPath}/${serviceName}/META-INF/</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Is there any suggestion to solution this? Another plugin to make changes in xml file?

Comment: It looks like resource filtering is the way to go here.  Can you try running maven with the `-X` option?  That way you can check whether everything is picked up correctly, it will show the runtime values of your configuration, all properties known by the maven process, the resources being filtered, ...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this profile is not active when running maven.

```
mvn -P local clean install
```